# Magnetic Based Lifeforms

Tags: biology, evolution, electromagnetism

It's typically regarded that life needs liquids of some kind to evolve.

But liquid is just a state where molecules can move around freely in order to interact with other molecules instead of being packed tightly in the solid state.

What if this "liquidity" was based on nano-particles of at least partially magnetic materials and strong oscillating/sloshing magnetic fields which causes the particles to move around and interact with each other?

I'm particularly interested in life in very cold places.  It seems to me that these lifeforms would be quite a bit larger than liquid based ones.

Am I nuts? :)

Comment: There was a story I read about beings on a magnetar neutron star, but can't remember if they were magnetic-based.

Comment: @Aaru Maybe Flux by Steven Baxter?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I recall a story, maybe two, where enormous magnetic structures lived out beyond the heliopause.

I recall one of "them" trying to make contact and sending a bolt of lightning through the ship; finally convinced the others of its kind that these little specs were life when a ship had an emergency eject of plasma-whatever and made a magnetic bubble.

This is [*The Sunborn* by Gregory Benford](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/119550/what-was-this-story-about-interstallar-magnetic-beings/119727#119727).  This is a sequel to *The Martian Race*.

Comment: I'd be really interested in reading the first story.  Do you remember if it was a short story or a novel?

Comment: I could not find it through Google. Another hint is that a magnetic flux structure was described as *sinew* and was a scarce sustanance resource. The mag creatures were then asked to keep the heliopause extended out, as it was dipping to close for our liking, and their feeding or something affects that. They wanted to move on to greener pastures, staying would be beneficial to us. If it's a different story, I have a feeling that the Mars tie-in is a Revelation Space short, but did not find it.  The length of the story was short.

Comment: Do you mind if I ask about this on [scifi.SE](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/)? I just read this and I also got really interested in reading this first story. I'll link back to this answer, of course.

Comment: Please, I'd love to find it again too.

Comment: @CássioRenan did you ever find it?

Comment: Sorry, I never got a notification when you responded to my comment. I see you asked a question there now. Let's hope someone knows about it :)

Comment: found it!  http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/119550/what-was-this-story-about-interstallar-magnetic-beings/119727#119727